# align Mvc3 Drop down list values center

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, center, alignment

I have this my view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode, Model.StateList, "Select", new { @style = "text-align : center" })
```

All the state abbreviations in the Drop Down List are aligning left. What should do to align them center?

@Jason Evans I don't think it is browser specific because I used this in the same view and it is aligning center.                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "", @style = "width:140px;text-align:center"})

Comment: Sorry, I meant the ability to centre the text of a `select` list could be browser specific.

Comment: The thing is, you shouldn't be able to do this, because it breaks the usability of the `<select>` element.  Users can't easily scan things that aren't left-aligned (or right-aligned in RTL languages).

So while I know in FF you _can_ do it doesn't mean you _should_ do it.

Comment: @Jason Evans Sorry, I understood your comment in a different way. In FF it is working but not in IE. Is there a way that makes it work in IE too?

Comment: @greg - Very, very good point! I didn't think of that myself. Having space on the left side of the text in the <option> part of the select list could mess things up for screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this functionality may be browser specific:

[how to make sure select option text align in the center in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911111/how-to-make-sure-select-option-text-align-in-the-center-in-ie)