# Setting DropDownListFor CSS for options

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following that sets my dropdown to a ridiculous width:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TypeId, new SelectList(Model.Type, "TypeId", "TypeName"), null, new {  @style = "width: 500;" })
                                </div>
```

How do I get the items that appear as options in the populated drop down to move their alignment e.g. center align the text?

This is what I am aiming for, what I think *should* work, which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardodeano/r7XeZ/18/).

[image: Center dropdown item text]

But as you can see, the option text is still over to the left. Any ideas?

Comment: See also this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911111/how-to-make-sure-select-option-text-align-in-the-center-in-ie) about centering the text in the select options in IE (tl;dr: you can't.)

Comment: And that, as they say is that! Thanks Roddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7XeZ/)

[**My New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7XeZ/24/)

Also **NOTE**, you are using 500px width, what's that for?

Comment: Hello Mr. Alien. The width of the dropdown is just a ridiculous entry so I can see clearly that the text would be either left, right or center :)

Comment: Not really no Mr. Alien. So I have taken your fiddle and expanded it slightly http://jsfiddle.net/ricardodeano/r7XeZ/13/.

Comment: I'm after the "This is my first" to be slap bang in the middle of that massive dropdown and text-align: center; doesn't appear to be doing what I would like it to do.

Comment: can you show an image of exactly how you want because this seems appropriate to what you asked

Comment: Sure - give me a couple of seconds.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas oh you want cross browser..I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is you goal here is.

But if I understood correct

```
<select class="ddl">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
</select>
```

***css***

```
.ddl{text-align: center; width:250px;}
option{text-align: center;}
```

Sample : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DSbBv/3/)

Comment: Is it work in Firefox?? Anyway, it that what you expect? I mean the one I created in jsfiddle