# Center items in DropDownList

Tags: c#, css, webforms

i have a problem with centering items (options) in dropdownlist in webForm application.

this is a table with ddl:

```
<table class="grid">
        <tr>
            <td class="gridPagerCell">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbFirstPage" runat="server" Text="<<" OnCommand="onPage_Command" CommandName="PAGING" CommandArgument="<<" />
            </td>
            <td class="gridPagerCell">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPreviosPage" runat="server" Text="<" OnCommand="onPage_Command" CommandName="PAGING" CommandArgument="<" />
            </td>

            <td class="gridPagerCell">
                <asp:DropDownList id="ddlSelectedPage" runat="server" CssClass="gridPagerDropDownList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectedPage_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </td>

            <td class="gridPagerCell">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbNextPage" runat="server" Text=">" OnCommand="onPage_Command" CommandName="PAGING" CommandArgument=">" />
            </td>
            <td class="gridPagerCell">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLastPage" runat="server" Text=">>" OnCommand="onPage_Command" CommandName="PAGING" CommandArgument=">>" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:100%; text-align:right;">
                <asp:Literal ID="ltTotalCount" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

in code behind i binding dropdownlist:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ddlSelectedPage.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= Helper.GetCountOfGridPages(this.TotalRecords, this.GridPageSize) - 1; i++)
            {
                var item = new ListItem((i + 1).ToString(), (i + 1).ToString());

                this.ddlSelectedPage.Items.Add(item);

            }
        }
```

this is a CSS Style:

```
    .gridPagerDropDownList
{
    width:125px;
    text-align:center;
    left: auto; 
}
.grid
{
    width:100%;
    color: #000000;
}
.gridPagerCell
{
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;

    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Problem is that in FF i see text in dropdown list in a center of dll, in IE and Chrome is text aligment to left, but i want it aligment in center in all browsers...

Any idea for solution?

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the behavior you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in many post, there is no cross-browser CSS that can align center select box.

- [how to make sure select option text align in the center in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911111/how-to-make-sure-select-option-text-align-in-the-center-in-ie)
- [is it possible to center text in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box)
- [select option text align](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/452197-select-option-text-align)
- ...

You could always make a script that will hide the select option and emulate it with a div-tree. I couldn't find any plugin that does it already, but there might be some out there.