# Horizontally text center for select option

Tags: html, css

I have this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/) with standard `<select>` html element, all what am trying to do is give center alignment for `<option>` tags.

I've tried already `text-indent: 20px` but its center only the visible tag in the select!

How can I center it?

Comment: It's been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1911111/1612146)

Comment: @oGeez if you meant this solution `&nbsp;&nbsp;` so no this not what am looking for. any thank thanks for your time.

Comment: An answer isn't always exactly what your looking for, there is no center align for `<option>`s. It's either spaces or padding (See [C Travel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19790792/1612146))

Comment: yea i got it already. once again thanks for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution 1:** *(A simple solution)*

```
select {
   ...    
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/1/)**

**Solution 2:** *(added 27-10-2017)* 
Only the selected number will be centered. 
* *Probably not yet supported by Safari*

```
select {
   ...
   text-align: center;
   text-align-last: center;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/719/)**

Comment: C Travel! thank you. 
damn how could i did't think about this one. once again thanks

Comment: No problem, its not a beautiful solution, but as i said 'a simple' one it is.

Comment: easy is not an option i agree. but when the client is on hurry and there's no time to explain so this is the best solution :) Cheers

Comment: Is this really what you want, check out what happens when applying options with extreme long values in this [updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/260/). Setting the `width` property to a fixed value causes strange appearances like this.

Comment: @Fleuv it was an example where the width is irrelevant, because i needed to show what you could do with padding. All the other css used in this demo is irrelevant for this case...

Comment: This perfectly centers the "longest" element.  All others are left justified.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use

```
select {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/2/)

Unfortunately, this works for Firefox only. For Chrome, you must use `padding-left` similar to @CTravel's solution

```
select {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5k4D/58/)

But this doesn't work on the `option` elements in Firefox, so this isn't a cross-browser solution either.

Comment: This pretty clearly does not give "center alignment for the <option> tags" as asked in the OP. This merely centers the select element.

Comment: @ColtMcCormack You pretty clearly use a different browser than I do. E.g. Chrome doesn't honor the `text-align` in either `select` or `option`. There, you must use a kludge like `padding-left`. I can't say for IE or Opera, since I don't use either one.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I believe that fix is indeed Firefox only, making it work on a small fraction of web clients (10-25% as of this writing according to a few different sources).

My only qualm was that the original answer seemed to indicate that it would always work, which may have confused CSS beginners who tried it. I have removed my TD now that you have clarified that this is for FF only (thanks!).

As an aside, the reason this doesn't work is because text-align only affects inline elements, of which <option> is not. I'm surprised that Firefox treats it as so.

Comment: Chrome will honor `text-align-last` for the `<select>` tag but not for the `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

don't use

```
select {
   ...    
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

or

```
select {
    text-align: center;
}
```

they are no working in select.
maybe you can use JQuery's select style:[JQuery UI Select](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-ui-selectmenu-an-aria-accessible-plugin-for-styling-a-html-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

as stated elsewhere, it is not possible with plain CSS. (Not for all browsers anyhow)