# CSS Help - Navigation Alignment

Tags: css

I'm not sure what I did but I broke the alignment on the dropdown portion of my navigation for my website https://shiftins.com. The site should show the sub navigation links centered and not aligned left. Can someone help me identify the code I need to change/add/fixed to make the sub navigation menu aligned again? Thanks!

Comment: i see them aligned left

Comment: They are aligned left so they clip with my logo the sub navigation should be center

Comment: Are you trying to get the individual links in your submenu to be aligned centered or are you trying to get the whole submenu to more closely match the alignment of your main nav menu (ie, be offset from your logo on the left)?

Comment: .nav-primary should be "left" and .genesis-nav-menu should be "center" but as I "zoom out", or increase pixel width, .genesis-nav-menu starts moving left. How can I get this to be fixed center regardless of zoom distance or screen width?

Comment: A cross-browser solution for this problem may not be via CSS - need JS/jQuery - check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box  and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790687/horizontally-text-center-for-select-option

Answer (score 1):

Change this part into "center" as you see here:

```
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: then try this:

`text-align: center !important;`

Comment: Ah actually it is working; however, the alignment shifts left as I "zoom out" or increase the resolution. How can I keep the alignment center regardless of what zoom or width I'm viewing at?

Comment: i guess there are `@media queries` in the css for different screen sizes.
look for `@media` and change the values to `center` for each screensize.